# Why jQuery load() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

Why the following jQuery code doesn't work? I put a div element in the body already. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").load("http://www.pagetutor.com/index.html");
});
```

Comment: Also, are you sure you mean to load the content into *every* <div> on the page at once?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without having more info:

You can't load remote domain content unless it's json content.

[This is a browser restriction.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)